# Auto add an anchor tag if currenttext === "@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName +<br>+ 'CP'"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add an anchor in a cell of a specific table according to its text. Here is what I got so far...

```
for (var d = 0, max = allTableCells.length; d < max; d++) {
    var node = allTableCells[d];
    var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    if (currentText === "@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName + 'TEXT'")
        node.childNodes[0].nodeValue = '<a name="CP"></a>'
    }
}
```

The main issue here seems to be those two lines...

```
if (currentText === "@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName + 'TEXT'")
    node.childNodes[0].nodeValue = '<a name="CP"></a>'
```

If anyone could help me, it would be nice... Thank you

Here is the complete script of the page:
    
        var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

```
for (var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];


    var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;


    if (currentText === "@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName")
        node.style.color = "Blue"; 
        node.style.border = "solid"


      }
     for (var c = 0, max = allTableCells.length; c < max; c++) {
    var node = allTableCells[c];
    var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;


    if (currentText === "None")
        node.style.color = "black";
    node.style.border = "solid"
}

var d, max, node, nodes, currentText, anchor;
for (d = 0, max = allTableCells.length; d < max; d++) {
node = allTableCells[d];
nodes = node.childNodes;
currentText = nodes[nodes.length - 1].nodeValue;    
if (@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName === nodes[0].nodeValue && currentText === 'CP') {
    anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.name = 'CP';
    allTableCells[d].insertBefore(anchor, nodes[0]);
}
```

}

```
</script>
```

Comment: The issue is that currentText === "@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName + 'TEXT'" condition is never true? Can you debug your code in the console and check the correct value?

Comment: Also [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue) is not purposed to add elements to HTML, you need to use [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) & [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) to achieve this.

Comment: So you're looking for the string... `BOB + 'TEXT'`? 'cos that's how you've written it... If you meant `BOBTEXT` then use brackets appropriately Also, I assume you're pre-processing this with Razor/something else to replace the username? If so, look at the actualy javascript generated through "view source"

Comment: I think you overestimate my capacities =P I've found this code on a forum and modify his effect. Now I'm just trying to make it right for this situation.

I know a good part is working because i'm already using it for another part of my project.
(The @WebSecurity.CurrentUserName is from webmatrix startersite.)
The anchor must be writted when a cell in a table got those two letters "CP". 

Teemu: I think you are right, but I'm not sure of the synthax =(

Comment: Basic: I mean a cell with <td>Bob<br>text random<br>CP</td>

Comment: @DanielLavoie Remove the quotes around `@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName` in the first `if` condition. Likely `"None"` is not a value of a node, perhaps you need `""` (empty string) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cell like `<td>Bob<br>text random<br>CP</td>` contains the `childNodes` below:

```
nodes = td.childNodes;
nodes[0] === Bob
nodes[1] === br element
nodes[2] === text random
nodes[3] === br element
nodes[4] === CP
```

Notice, that if `</td>` is not on the same line with `CP`, there will be also `nodes[5] === empty text node`.

If the text you want to check (said `CP` in a comment) always is in the last node, you need to change your code like this:

```
var d, max, node, nodes, currentText, currentUser, anchor;
for (d = 0, max = allTableCells.length; d < max; d++) {
    node = allTableCells[d];
    nodes = node.childNodes;
    currentUser = parent.@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
    currentText = nodes[nodes.length - 1].nodeValue;    
    if (currentUser === nodes[0].nodeValue && currentText === 'CP') {
        anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.name = 'CP';
        allTableCells[d].insertBefore(anchor, nodes[0]);
    }
}
```

[A simplified demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KNfHf/1/).

---

**EDIT**

In the comments you've told that this code is executed in an iframe. I assume `@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName` is defined in the main window. Make sure it's a global variable in the main window, then you can use the edited snippet above.

Comment: The page is loaded in a Iframe from another pages called main.cshtml#CP...
In order to get <td> achored the <td> value must have @websecurity.currentusername and the letter cp on the las line.

Comment: I tryed to get your code working and it seem I don't understand quite enough. 
Also can you explain de difference between this code you are showing me and the on in simplified demo?

Comment: Oh After a few test I think it's partly working. It's creating an anchor but not in the <td> with the @Websecurity.Currentusername

Comment: How can I edit my question?
if (currentText === "@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName + <br> + '*' + <br> + 'CP'")

Comment: The td contains a name, a line for text and sometimes (one per person) "CP"
The user is logged in and the var is @websecurty.currentusername

Comment: I'm really sorry for my english. It's hard for me to fully understand =) My apologies.
If @websecurity.username = the name in the <td>
And if the <td> got 'cp' then add the anchor

Comment: @DanielLavoie Don't worry about english, mine is poor as well ; ). Anyway, how we get the actual value of `@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName`? Or is it an object...? Just a second, I'll make an edit to my answer...

Comment: it's a variable created when you login it's the username. The variable has already been created

Comment: The code doesn't seem to work... When I load the page nothing move the <iframe> still look the table from default space

Comment: @DanielLavoie Are the anchors there now? I mean that's what you originally asked. I think we also should remove some comments here, there's a ton of them already...

Comment: The anchors doesn't seem to be there... =/ How can I be sure. I inspect the boject and I don't see the anchors and my Ifram doesn't load on it

Comment: @DanielLavoie You can use `console.log()` to check the `innerHTML`, just like in the fiddle linked in my answer. Please notice the edit to my answer too, this might be the issue now, since earlier you've stated "`It's creating an anchor...`.

Comment: I've modified my question with my full script... The rest is working well... miraculously

Comment: @DanielLavoie Huh... Please hit `F12` on a page, and you'll find out ; ). More info of [`console.log()` in FF](http://getfirebug.com/logging)... All (desktop)browsers have some kind of a developer tools, using them will make life easier, or at least coding...

Comment: Oh ok that thing =D. Ok now everything work... The last detail is ta the td is going on top is there a way to look it mor centered?
This is what I did
    if (nodes[0].nodeValue === '@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName'  && currentText === 'CP')

Comment: @DanielLavoie Maybe you better post another question about centering. I still wonder, how it could work, if you've enclosed `@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName` in the parenteheses, you shouldn't, it's a variable, not a string...